# Let's brainstorm some good chat events

Tags: discussion, chat

I don't know how it works exactly, but it looks like SE chat rooms can hold scheduled events. For example, [Science Fiction & Fantasy](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/science-fiction-fantasy?tab=schedule) has a recurring event for book recommendation.

As an SE site about Japanese language & usage, how can we take advantage of this feature? What are some fun and/or useful event themes?

---

**Update:** How scheduled event works:

I couldn't find any official help document about it, but it looks like **room owners** can create a **scheduled event** from the 'schedule' tab of a room's info page.

[image]

And then, other users can **sign up** ("register" in the screenshot below) to let everyone know s/he's coming.

[image]

I guess that's the extent of the built-in functionality for scheduled events; when the time comes, we're on our own to gather and do whatever the event is about. Later, anyone can manually [bookmark](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#permalink) the conversation for posterity's sake (Science Fiction & Fantasy's room has examples of such bookmarked conversations [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/science-fiction-fantasy?tab=conversations)).

Comment: probably create a specific new chat room for whatever event or topic you decide to do would be good.

Comment: I've added more details about how "scheduled" events work. Having dedicated rooms for specific event/topic, as @Mark says, is a good idea too. For example, Ask Ubuntu has a ["Classroom" room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/663/classroom?tab=schedule).

Comment: Do we know how many "good speakers" are in which timezone?  If there isn't someone qualified to help others during the chat, it is unlikely to improve one's Japanese…

Answer (score 3):

**Japanese conversation hour**

At my university, they used to have a weekly *日本語アワー* for people to come and interact with each other in Japanese and learn about Japanese culture. It might be nice to have a Japanese chat (in Japanese) for an hour or so.

However, writing is likely not as easy as speaking, for many people, so this may be more difficult for beginners to participate in.

Answer (score 2):

**Movie Night**

Watch the same movie or TV show together, on our respective Blu-ray/DVD/VHS player. We can ask and debate about unclear or interesting points.

The movie has to be in Japanese, of course.

Comment: At what time is night? ;-)

Comment: That's the problem I have - when I get on chat, no one else is there!

Comment: It's a major problem with real time socialization space with a small user base.. I think we'll either have to vote, let someone decide, or do a long-running event, like a whole day.

Answer (score 2):

**Memorization techniques**

I always get great tips when talking with other learners about how they memorize Japanese vocabulary.

Since it is subjective, it is better to discuss it on this way, rather than with real SE questions.